# animation of filling-up an oval

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the ImageView src =

```
<shape android:shape="oval">

<stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

I want to fill up it and use an another drawable for a final state:

```
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

How animate this action?

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4SSI.png)

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Vector animations from design library
[VectorAnimation](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)